# Datepicker glyphicon validation not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, datepicker, glyphicons

I'm trying a date picker in my form.. I'd used the bootstrap glyphicon validation to validate it..But even when I'm selected the date from picker it shows the validation error message for required field..How could I fix this problem..Below is my script..

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datepicker')
        .datepicker({
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            startDate: '01/01/2010',
            endDate: '12/30/2020'
        })
        .on('changeDate', function(e) {
            // Revalidate the date field
            $('#myform').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
        });

    $('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            date: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Last date is required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        min: '01/01/2010',
                        max: '12/30/2020',
                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                    }
                }
            },

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

And my form:

```
<form method="post" id="myform" class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="control-label col-xs-2">Date</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="date" id="datepicker"  placeholder="Date" >
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-4 col-xs-10">
         <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg " type="submit" >Submit</button>
           </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date is not validating because you are trying to validate it with [formvalidation](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-ui-datepicker/) UI datepicker `$('#myform').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');` with `.on('changeDate', function(e)` where otherhand you are using [Bootstrapvalidator](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) plugin to validate the date input field `$('#myform').bootstrapValidator()`

Simple words you are trying to use 2 different validation plugins together.

At this point, not sure which plugin you want to use to validate the date field, will post the solution with both `formValidation` and `Bootstrapvalidation`

**Solution with `Bootstrapvalidation`**

JS script will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },

        fields: {
            date: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Last date is required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        min: '01/01/2010',
                        max: '12/30/2020',
                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    });
});
```

and `datepicker` validation will be

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            $('#myform').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'date');
        }
    });
});
```

As you are using jQuery Datepicker, you can't validate it with `onChange` like your approach in question, you have to validate it with `OnSelect`

[Bootstrap Validator Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bk1o5ap7/)

---

**Solution with `formValidation`**

JS will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            date: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Last date is required'
                    },
                    date: {
                        format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
                        min: '01/01/2010',
                        max: '12/30/2020',
                        message: 'The date is not a valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }).find('[name="date"]')
        .datepicker({
        onSelect: function (date, inst) {
            // Revalidate the field when choosing it from the datepicker
            $('#myform').formValidation('revalidateField', 'date');
        }
    });
});
```

As you are using jQuery Datepicker, you can't validate it with `onChange` like your approach in question, you have to validate it with `OnSelect`

[formValidation Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xqyyree/)

Comment: Appreciable..! But unfortunately the same code is not working with me..It is showing the bootstrap validate error for an empty field.. :(

Comment: can you update this fiddle with the code you are using http://jsfiddle.net/bk1o5ap7/, just add the script and save and past the link here